# Django WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/chat/lobby/ [127.0.0.1:3022]

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i want to create chat app, i follow the https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_2.html here,

```
chat/
    __init__.py
    routing.py
    urls.py
    settings.py
    wsgi.py
```

i added this code to my **routing.py**

```
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
import chat.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (http->django views is added by default)
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

in my settings.py

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'Accounting.routing.application'
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

in my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('chat/', include('chat.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

in my chat app

```
chat/
    __init__.py
    consumers.py
    routing.py
    templates/
        chat/
            index.html
            room.html
    urls.py
    views.py
```

i have consumers.py

```
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
import json

class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name

        # Join room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        # Send message to room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

this is the code in my chat>routing.py

```
from django.urls import re_path

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer),
]
```

in my chat>views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'chat/index.html', {})

def room(request, room_name):
    return render(request, 'chat/room.html', {
        'room_name': room_name
    })
```

i have urls.py in my chat app

from django.urls import path

```
from . import views
app_name = 'chat'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<str:room_name>/', views.room, name='room'),
]
```

i follow all the direction, i copy paste the code, the placement of py, everything in the turorial, but still i get this error

[image]

did i miss something?

UPDATE

[image]

when i tried this in my pycharm terminal 
**docker run -p 6379:6379 -d redis:2.8**

[image]

Comment: Did you run redis server?

Comment: redis server? whats that?

Comment: `CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
        },
    },
}`

You are adding this code on your settings because of django-channels puts processes on a queue system. That system is redis which used by django-channels. So you should run it. Running it with docker `docker run -p 6379:6379 -d redis:2.8`

Comment: i get same result

Comment: i update my question mr @ishakO.

Comment: install redis on your computer. And then run it.

Comment: when you create a message in your thread view `ChatMessage.objects.create` you need to publish this to a go channels group so that any subscriber gets notified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a few things have issues here.

1) you are mixing `async` and `sync` consumer code.

I suggest just using the `async consumer` all you methods then should be `async` methods.

It looks like you are calling `get_thread` from a sync context but `get_thread` has been wrapped in `database_sync_to_async` so needs to be Called from an async context (and needs to be awaited).

you also need to `await` `self.channel_layer.group_add`

2) in your `ThreadView` you have a `ChatMessage.objects.create` here you should also send a message over the thread channel group.

```py
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
channel_layer = get_channel_layer()

async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(f"thread_{thread.id}", {"type": "chat.message", "text": ...})
```

you also need to save the Chat message to the DB in your websocket_receive.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your `settings.py` file a template variable called `CHANNEL_LAYER` is enabled (that is the exact cause of the error), so try to remove this piece of code from project/settings.py

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': '',
        'CONFIG': {
           "hosts":[127.0.0.1],
        },
    },
}
```

In my case it was the root cause of the error. If it doesn't work try to change your chat/routing.py file.

Answer (score 0):

ADD ".as_asgi()"

```
from django.urls import re_path

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got into the same problem, its the server disconnected issue and that causes all these.
https://github.com/tporadowski/redis/releases/tag/v5.0.9
Download the latest version and run the  redis-server application. It solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

If you're in linux

1. First install docker by run this command - `sudo snap install docke`r
2. Then run this command - `sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock`
3. Then run this command `docker run -p 6379:6379 -d redis:5` and start Django server. It will probably resolve that issue. It worked for me and I guess it is pretty much the same for Windows and Mac.